# C++ matrix of enum

Tags: c++, matrix, enums

I have an enum defined as

```
enum my_type_t {
  UNKNOWN, TYPE1, TYPE2
};
```

I want to declare a matrix where the two dimensions `num_of_edges` and `num_of_nodes` are provided by user at run time. I also want to pass the matrix by reference to the called function.

I have declared the matrix as

```
vector< vector<my_type_t> > my_matrix(num_of_edges, vector<my_type_t> (num_of_nodes, UNKNOWN));
```

I have passed it from main like this

```
main () {
  int edge1 = 5; 
  int node1 = 10;
  my_function(i, j, my_matrix);
  i = 12;
  j = 4;
  my_function(i, j, my_matrix);
}
```

and declaration of `my_function` is

```
void my_function(int i, int j, vector< vector<my_type_t> >& my_matrix) {
  // some code
  if (my_condition == true)
    my_matrix[i][j] = TYPE1;
  else
    my_matrix[i][j] = TYPE2;
  // some other code
}
```

I am getting the following compiler error:

```
no known conversion for argument 4 from std::vector<std::vector<my_type_t> >’ to ‘int&’
```

Please help.

Comment: You need to show a specific error or problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Updated question with details.

Comment: You need to add a complete example + complete error message, because there is no functions here which has at least 4 arguments (looking at the error message, there must be one).

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't match the error message. The latter points to the 4th argument of a function that only has 3 arguments. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You can create a two dimensional vector like so:

```
size_t num_rows = 10;
size_t num_cols = 20;

std::vector<std::vector<my_type_t>> matrix(num_rows, std::vector<my_type_t>(num_cols));
```

You need to initialize the outer vector with copies of the inner vectors in order to have a rectangular data structure. The problem with this is that there is no guarantee that all the lengths of the vectors stay the same. Therefore it might be sensible to wrap this into a class to enforce the invariants that you want.

Alternatively you can use the Boost `multi_array` which handles nested `std::vector` with a nicer API.